# Nuxt 3 upload image with proxy

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I need to upload an image to the backend.

On the frontend, I get an image and set an image from the FileList

```
formData.append("image", files[0]);
```

To communicate with the server I need to use a proxy. First, I collect all the data and send it to the next server, and then I will send it to the backend, which is written in python. The problem is that my image is not accepted by the backend and I get an error `Upload a valid image. The file you uploaded was either not an image or a corrupted image.` The server is most likely working correctly, because using curl it turns out to successfully download the file.This happens exactly with images, when you upload a file, everything is fine. The problem disappears if you use the nitro proxy and other libraries, but I need to use the solution through the nuxt server

**What do I need to do to send images correctly? Read Form Data on the server and send a real backend? Or do I need to change the headers?**

**Frontend**

```js
async updateConsultant(formData: consultantsType | FormData, slug: string) {
           
            const { data, error } = await useFetch(`/api/consultant/${slug}/`, {
                method: "PATCH",
                baseURL: useRuntimeConfig().public.PROXY_PATH,
                //headers: { "Content-Type": `multipart/form-data;` },
                body: formData,
            });
            if (error.value) {
            
            } else {
              ;
            }
          
        },
```

**Nuxt 3 server**

```js
export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
    const method = event.method;
    const params = getQuery(event);

    const headers = getRequestHeaders(event);

    const url = getRequestURL(event).pathname.replace("/proxy", "");
    let body = method === "GET" ? undefined : await readBody(event);

    const response = await $fetch.raw(url, {
        headers: {
            ...(headers["storage"] && {
                storage: headers["storage"],
            }),
            ...(headers["content-type"] && {
                "Content-Type": headers["content-type"],
            }),
            Accept: "application/json",
            Authorization:
                parseCookies(event).auth && `Bearer ${parseCookies(event).auth}`,
            "x-tenant": parseCookies(event).tenant && parseCookies(event).tenant,
        },
        baseURL,
        method,
        params,
        body,
    });   
    return response._data;
});
```